# How to trigger javascript function in on_change event in Odoo

Tags: javascript, cursor, odoo, odoo-8

How can I trigger a javascript function from on_change event?

This is what I need to achieve:

1. User input in Field_1 > Cursor move focus to Field_3
2. User input in Field_3 > Cursor move back focus to Field_1

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: <form>

       <field name="input1"/>

 <field name="input2"/>

</form>


When user input in field input1, the cursor automatically moves to input2, vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Get your field dom elements and then you need to listen the event *'change'*, like this:

```
<your_field1>.on('change', function() {
    <your_field2>.focus()  
}
```

And the same for the backward operation.

Do you know how to declare and register a js widget?